# Deleting files by type in Python on Windows

Tags: python, file

I know how to delete single files, however I am lost in my implementation of how to delete all files in a directory of one type.

Say the directory is \myfolder

I want to delete all files that are .config files, but nothing to the other ones.
How would I do this?

Thanks Kindly

Comment: Did you mean you want to delete all *files* that are .config?

Comment: do you want to delete all .config files under a certain path?  if you just want to delete a .config file, then you can just do os.remove(".config")

Comment: Yes I want to delete all .config files that are contained in a certain directory.

Comment: A directory and all it's subdirectories, or just the directory?

Comment: The question is a duplicate, a neat explanation is provided here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995373/deleting-all-files-in-a-directory-with-python

Answer (score 17):

Use the [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) module:

```
import os
from glob import glob

for f in glob ('myfolder/*.config'):
   os.unlink (f)
```

Comment: +1: Yep, glob is the right approach here (if you don't want to walk sub-directories, of course -- that would need os.walk).

Answer (score 5):

I would do something like the following:

```
import os
files = os.listdir("myfolder")
for f in files:
  if not os.path.isdir(f) and ".config" in f:
    os.remove(f)
```

It lists the files in a directory and if it's not a directory and the filename has ".config" anywhere in it, delete it.  You'll either need to be in the same directory as myfolder, or give it the full path to the directory.  If you need to do this recursively, I would use the os.walk [function](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk).

Comment: I actually meant files, not folders. Sorry Dan

Comment: Not your fault - but this answer is now irrelevant due to OP editing the question.

Comment: note that this will delete files like 'my.config.bak'. Probably not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 1):

Here ya go:

```
import os

# Return all files in dir, and all its subdirectories, ending in pattern
def gen_files(dir, pattern):
   for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(dir):
      for f in files:
         if f.endswith(pattern):
            yield os.path.join(dirname, f)


# Remove all files in the current dir matching *.config
for f in gen_files('.', '.config'):
   os.remove(f)
```

Note also that `gen_files` can be easily rewritten to accept a tuple of patterns, since `str.endswith` accepts a tuple