# Deleting all files in a directory with Python

Tags: python, file-io

I want to delete all files with the extension `.bak` in a directory. How can I do that in Python?

Comment: note: to delete an entire directory tree [`shutil.rmtree(path)` could used](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete the contents of a folder in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185936/how-to-delete-the-contents-of-a-folder-in-python)

Answer (score 319, accepted):

Via [`os.listdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) and [`os.remove`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.remove):

```
import os

filelist = [ f for f in os.listdir(mydir) if f.endswith(".bak") ]
for f in filelist:
    os.remove(os.path.join(mydir, f))
```

Using only a single loop:

```
for f in os.listdir(mydir):
    if not f.endswith(".bak"):
        continue
    os.remove(os.path.join(mydir, f))
```

Or via [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob):

```
import glob, os, os.path

filelist = glob.glob(os.path.join(mydir, "*.bak"))
for f in filelist:
    os.remove(f)
```

Be sure to be in the correct directory, eventually using [`os.chdir`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chdir).

Comment: Your first example is using redundant for loops.  You can one pass with -
[ os.remove(f) for f in os.listdir(".") if f.endswith(".bak") ] - 
as list comprehensions are meant to be used.  Or you can move the 'if' in the comprehension into the for loop - 
for f in os.listdir("."):
    if f.endswith(".bak"):
        os.remove(f)

Comment: @slh2080 Since you say the problem has been solved, why not mark the answer as the correct answer?

Comment: Watch out the os.listdir(".")!!! I used this code and forgot to change the path, all my code were gone!!! Tried two different utilities to recover but with no luck!!

Comment: @LeiGuo Fixed that.

Comment: @dragonjujo I would argue that invoking side effects are very much _not_ how list comprehensions are meant to be used.

Comment: pretty sure the second example has a "not" too much!

Answer (score 28):

In Python 3.5, [`os.scandir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.scandir) is better if you need to check for file attributes or type - see [`os.DirEntry`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.DirEntry) for properties of the object that's returned by the function.

```
import os 

for file in os.scandir(path):
    if file.name.endswith(".bak"):
        os.unlink(file.path)
```

This also doesn't require changing directories since each `DirEntry` already includes the full path to the file.

Comment: You're missing a colon, the first line inside the for loop should be `if file.name.endswith(".bak"):`

Comment: Thanks! That'll teach me to write code without actually running them

Comment: hi, how to create path object ?

Answer (score 26):

Use `os.chdir` to change directory .
Use `glob.glob` to generate a list of file names which end it '.bak'. The elements of the list are just strings.

Then you could use `os.unlink` to remove the files. (PS. `os.unlink` and `os.remove` are synonyms for the same function.)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import glob
import os
directory='/path/to/dir'
os.chdir(directory)
files=glob.glob('*.bak')
for filename in files:
    os.unlink(filename)
```

Answer (score 8):

you can create a function. Add maxdepth as you like for traversing subdirectories.

```
def findNremove(path,pattern,maxdepth=1):
    cpath=path.count(os.sep)
    for r,d,f in os.walk(path):
        if r.count(os.sep) - cpath <maxdepth:
            for files in f:
                if files.endswith(pattern):
                    try:
                        print "Removing %s" % (os.path.join(r,files))
                        #os.remove(os.path.join(r,files))
                    except Exception,e:
                        print e
                    else:
                        print "%s removed" % (os.path.join(r,files))

path=os.path.join("/home","dir1","dir2")
findNremove(path,".bak")
```

Answer (score 2):

First [glob](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) them, then [unlink](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.unlink).

Comment: Link-only answer. Answers should contain the relevant part. If the link is removed, this is just a comment. [answer] "First glob them, then unlink." seems like a LQA or NAA.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is old; however, here would be how to do so using just the os module...

```
def purgedir(parent):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(parent):                                      
        for item in files:
            # Delete subordinate files                                                 
            filespec = os.path.join(root, item)
            if filespec.endswith('.bak'):
                os.unlink(filespec)
        for item in dirs:
            # Recursively perform this operation for subordinate directories   
            purgedir(os.path.join(root, item))
```

Answer (score 0):

For one line solution (Both `Windows` and `Linux`) ;

```
import glob,os

for file in glob.glob("<your_path>/*.bak"): print(file," these will be deleted")

if input("continue ?") == "Y":
    for file in glob.glob("<your_path>/*.bak"): os.remove(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or using pathlib.Path:

```
from pathlib import Path

for file in Path("/path/to/folder").glob("*"):
    file.unlink()
```

This way one also could specify to only delete files that match the glob pattern. For example: .glob("*.txt") to only remove text files.

And for a recursive removal of all files in subfolders just use rglob instead of glob. The following would delete all txt-files in the specified folder and all it's subfolders:

```
for file in Path("/path/to/folder").rglob("*.txt"):
    file.unlink()
```

Answer (score -1):

On Linux and macOS you can run simple command to the shell:

```
subprocess.run('rm /tmp/*.bak', shell=True)
```

Comment: Not a good choice in my opinion. It's not portable and it's probably more expensive due to the extra subprocess. Better to use Python APIs.

Comment: this solution is platform dependent, whereas Python is platform agnostic.

Comment: On the other hand, not being able to empty a directory with a single command is insane, so this is simple and elegant.