# Verifying that os.remove has worked

Tags: python

To [delete a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995373/deleting-files-in-python), I'm using [os.remove](http://docs.python.org/library/os#os.remove).

The docs (linked) don't give any indication of any exceptions except for [OSError](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.OSError):

> If path is a directory, OSError is raised

How do I check for exceptions such as `FileNotFound`, `PermissionToDeleteDenied`, etc? Or is such error checking not done by the `os.remove` function (the docs for `os.remove` and `os.unlink` don't seem to say)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`OSError` exceptions have an `errno` attribute which you can use together with the `errno` module to get more information about what type of OS error occurred.  See [the documentation for OSError](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.OSError).

Comment: Python 3.3 will add [separate exception classes](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/exceptions.html#os-exceptions) for each error so checking `errno` won't be needed.

Answer (score -4):

Use this code:

```
import os
if(os.path.exists("c:/randomDirectory/random.txt"):
    # some random code
```

it runs the random code if random.txt exists.

Comment: This won't tell me why my `os.remove` *doesn't* run if, say, the file isn't owned by the current user, or if it's a directory instead of a file, or if the files currently in use, or a bunch of other possible errors.

Comment: It does not tell permission denied problem, etc.