# Impossible to delete files in a loop with python

Tags: python, glob, shutil, eoserror

I want delete files on a folder and I have an error.

My code

```
for f in glob ('sub/*.sub'):
     subprocess.call(["php", "AES.class.php" , f])
     shutil.rmtree(f)
     #deplacement des fichier
     for d in glob ('*.ass'):
          shutil.move(d, 'sync')
```

It gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "start.py", line 26, in <module>
    shutil.rmtree(f)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/shutil.py", line 239, in rmtree
    onerror(os.listdir, path, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/shutil.py", line 237, in rmtree
    names = os.listdir(path)
OSError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: 'sub/Ep01.sub'
```

How to delete the files with extension `.sub` in folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want [`os.remove`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.remove) rather than `shutil.rmtree`.  Specifically, the former method is for removing a *file* whereas the latter is designed to remove a *directory* (along with all of it's contents).

```
for f in glob ('sub/*.sub'):
     subprocess.call(["php", "AES.class.php" , f])
     os.remove(f)
     #deplacement des fichier
     for d in glob ('*.ass'):
          shutil.move(d, 'sync')
```

Answer (score 2):

You have an exemple here [Deleting all files in a directory with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1995373/deleting-all-files-in-a-directory-with-python)

```
import os

filelist = [ f for f in os.listdir(".") if f.endswith(".bak") ]
for f in filelist:
    subprocess.call(["php", "AES.class.php" , f])
    os.remove(f)
```