# os.unlink multiple file in python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Deleting files by type in Python on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991279/deleting-files-by-type-in-python-on-windows)

How can I delete all files with the extension ".txt" in a directory? I normally just do

```
import os
filepath = 'C:\directory\thefile.txt'
os.unlink(filepath)
```

Is there a command like `os.unlink('C:\directory\*.txt')` that would delete all .txt files? How can I do that?
Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import glob
import os

for i in glob.glob(u'*.txt'):
  os.unlink (i)
```

should do the job.

Edit: You can also do it in "one line" using `map` operation:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import glob
import os

map(os.unlink, glob.glob(u'*.txt'))
```

Comment: Use `u'*.txt'` (note the `u` at the start of the string) to handle filenames containing Unicode characters.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/library/glob.html) module to get a list of files matching the pattern and call `unlink` on all of them in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through all files in `C:\directory\`, check if the extension is `.txt`, unlink if yes.